# Issue with "open_now" of google place api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

[image]

Hello, I am using the google map api and google places api, and I have this issue in large quantities. In fact, with each call to google places api:

"open_now is deprecated as of November 2019 and will be turned off in November 2020. Use the isOpen() function from a PlacesService.getDetails()"

I read the doc and did some research but I was told that I should not use open_now.

I don't use open_now or isOpen() in my project

Anyone to solve this issue ?

```
const map = store.state.map;
const google = store.state.google;
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
const center = map.getCenter();
const nearbySearchRequest = {
  location: center,
  radius: 650,
  types: ["restaurant"]
};

function nearbySearchCallback(results, status) {
const API_KEY = firebaseConfig.apiKey;
if (status == 'OK') {
  let restaurants = results;

  restaurants.forEach((restaurant, i) => {
    // For each restaurant, we get the reviews
    function getDetailsCallback(reviews) {
      restaurant.reviews = reviews;
    }

    const getDetailsRequest = {
      fields: ["reviews"],
      placeId: restaurant.place_id
    };
    service.getDetails(getDetailsRequest, getDetailsCallback);


    //For each restaurant, we get the image
    const lat = restaurant.geometry.location.lat();
    const lng = restaurant.geometry.location.lng();
    restaurant.img = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=150x150&location=${lat},${lng}&key=${API_KEY}`;
  });

  store.commit("UPDATE_RESTAU", restaurants);
  setMarkers();
}
}

service.nearbySearch(nearbySearchRequest, nearbySearchCallback);
```

Comment: Doesn't happen in the [example in the documentatoni](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination) ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b5g7s96h/) using that code).  Can you provide a [mcve] using your code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/thgjxcwq/; This seems to be an intended behavior since [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) return all of the available data fields, including opening_hours. I suggest that you file an issue for this on Google Maps [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188851%2B) to remove the error if you are not explicitly using opening_hours data field.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the “open_now()” function. I created some invisible text boxes to hold an Open or Closed status based on the current date/time. Then I added some javascript to populate those text boxes based on date/time, holiday and weekends. Finally, I added a function to my object array, in this case, airports, to get the value from the textboxes for the Open/Closed status.

I think this could be better explained by showing you a sample. Here’s a link to my CodePen where I placed it. Sometimes it works fine on CodePen and sometimes it doesn’t. But, it always works great if you just download the project and run it from your computer. Or, just copy/paste the “html, css and javascript” from the pen.

https://codepen.io/pailwriter/pen/MWyevGO

Please replace the API key with your own.

You can break out the 3 sections on the javascript page into 3 different js pages. Just take note of the order their in and in the "head" section of your html page, call them in that order.

Here's a quick look at the date/time JavaScript to work with.

```
var today = new Date();
var dateNow = today.getFullYear()+','+(today.getMonth()+1)+','+today.getDate();
var holidays = (
            '2020,1,1', 
            '2020,1,20', 
            '2020,2,17',
            '2020,5,25',
            '2020,7,3',
            '2020,9,7',
            '2020,10,12',
            '2020,11,11',
            '2020,11,26',
            '2020,12,25'
            );
var d = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
  
// Start Clock - H:m only
setInterval(function(){
  var tdate = new Date();
  var tformat = [
      ("0" + tdate.getHours()).substr(-2)
    , ("0" + tdate.getMinutes()).substr(-2)
  ].join(":");

//Based on current date/time, populate the "invisible" text boxes on the index.html page. *********************************
    // Open/Closed status for Monday through Friday only
                if (tformat > '09:00' && tformat < '17:00' && n != "Sunday" && n != "Saturday" && holidays != dateNow) {
                    document.getElementById("Shift1").innerHTML = "Open";
                    document.getElementById("Shift1").value = "Open";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("Shift1").innerHTML = "Closed";
                    document.getElementById("Shift1").value = "Closed"; 
                }

    // Open/Closed status for Monday - Saturday
                if (n == "Saturday" && tformat > '08:00' && tformat < '17:00' && holidays != dateNow || n != "Saturday" && n != "Sunday" && holidays != dateNow && tformat > '09:00' && tformat < '13:00') {
                    document.getElementById("Shift2").innerHTML = "Open";
                    document.getElementById("Shift2").value = "Open"; 
                }  
                else {
                    document.getElementById("Shift2").innerHTML = "Closed";
                    document.getElementById("Shift2").value = "Closed"; 
                }       
// Main Branch Hours Only ********************************* End *****************************************************
                            
// This is the closing tag for all the time/date options above. Do not remove. 
}, 100);
```